# SQL Server Datediff() function not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, datediff

For SQL Server I have some difficulty getting the difference between times

I'm using the SQuirell client but am unsure if Datediff is a function

Example of my data

```
Person | Times Ordered | Date order placed | Date order placed (Timestamp) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Jane   |      1        |   5/5/2017        |  5/5/2017 01:01:56.95
Jane   |      2        |   6/2/2017        |  6/2/2017 18:41:34.486
Jane   |      3        |   7/5/2018        |  7/5/2018 08:31:45.759
Donald |      1        |   5/2/2017        |  5/2/2017 21:22:44.23 
Donald |      2        |   8/2/2018        |  8/2/2018 22:25:50.323 
Ron    |      1        |   4/8/2017        |  4/8/2017 03:10:25.55
Ron    |      2        |   8/30/2017       |  8/30/2017 19:20:20.55
Ron    |      3        |   5/24/2018       |  5/24/2018 09:35:55.85
Jim    |      1        |   2/15/2017       |  2/15/2017 20:15:55.45 
Jim    |      2        |   9/6/2018        |  9/6/2018 23:20:50.4
```

I've tried the following SQL Server query

```
select
a.Person,
a.times_ordered,
a.date_order_placed,
datediff(month, lag(a.Date_order_placed_ts) over(partition by a.persion order by a.date_order_placed)) as Month_Difference
from table_1 a
```

Errors I'm getting

SQLERRMC: MONTH
SQLState:  42703
ErrorCode: -206

SQLERRMC: MONTH
SQLState:  56098
ErrorCode: -727

I'm trying to get the difference in time between the most recent order and the order just placed before that.

Desired Output Example

```
Person | Times Ordered | Date order placed | Date order placed (Timestamp) | Month_difference
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jane   |      1        |   5/5/2017        |  5/5/2017 01:01:56.95         | <Null>
Jane   |      2        |   6/2/2017        |  6/2/2017 18:41:34.486        |   1
Jane   |      3        |   7/5/2018        |  7/5/2018 08:31:45.759        |   13
Donald |      1        |   5/2/2017        |  5/2/2017 21:22:44.23         | <Null>
Donald |      2        |   8/2/2018        |  8/2/2018 22:25:50.323        |   15
Ron    |      1        |   4/8/2017        |  4/8/2017 03:10:25.55         | <Null>
Ron    |      2        |   8/30/2017       |  8/30/2017 19:20:20.55        |   4
Ron    |      3        |   5/24/2018       |  5/24/2018 09:35:55.85        |   9
Jim    |      1        |   2/15/2017       |  2/15/2017 20:15:55.45        | <Null>
Jim    |      2        |   9/6/2018        |  9/6/2018 23:20:50.4          |   19
```

Comment: `DateDiff()` takes three parameters and you've only supplied two. Instead: `datediff(month, lag(a.Date_order_placed) over(partition by a.persion order by a.date_order_placed), a.Date_order_placed)`?

Comment: I don't know what the error codes mean, but you are missing the third argument to `datediff()`.

Comment: Those error messages look like DB2 not SQL Server

Comment: I tried using the third parameter, a.Date_order_placed, and still get the same errors.

Perhaps I missed tagged this as SQL server when it should be DB2? I'm still confused with the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function in db2.
Try [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000861.html) instead.